23.10 does not power-off after shutdown
... the screen keeps showing the Ubuntu icon, I must keep the mechanical switch pressed for five seconds in order to obtain power-off. I hoped that the almost daily updates would have solved the problem but now, after many months, I must ask for help

This is not a universal problem. This is most commonly issue specific to certain models of hardware.

It also happens to me a few times (Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS), but since this is (probably) an ACPI bug, there's a few attempts to work around with this.

Try Alt+Print Screen+O. This is a system request command to shut down your computer. If it didn't work, try Alt+Print Screen+B, to (force) restart it. Make sure you did click "Shut Down" from the system menu, to confirm all files are saved.
Try updating your BIOS. There might be a chance it'll get fixed.
Try booting a live usb of different Ubuntu versions, since 23.10 is still quite buggy.


Please quote the source of the comment that Ubuntu 23.10 is buggy.
